# Can I couple non-terminals in context-free grammars?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

If I had productions like so...

$S \rightarrow A1B$

$A \rightarrow \epsilon$

$A \rightarrow 0$

$B \rightarrow \epsilon$

$B \rightarrow 1$

If I only want strings $\{\epsilon1\epsilon, 011\}$, am I allowed to choose when both $A$ and $B$ become $\epsilon$? Or will I get resulting strings such as $\epsilon11$ and $01\epsilon$? (I know the $\epsilon$'s disappear, but I just left them in to avoid confusion.)

If I get the unwanted strings, then how would you force both $A$ and $B$ to be $\epsilon$ only when you need them to be, while still having $A$ and $B$ result in different *terminals*?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to *one* question per post. I don't see how your last line relates to the rest, so I'm removing it.

Comment: Is there a website I can go to to actually have an open discussion on a topic? I do not like the strict question structure here.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound ungrateful, but most of my questions get downvoted. I understand, because some questions might sound weird. The reason is, while they are indeed from a list of questions. I only want hints, not solutions, so I have to refrain from posting the entire question. So when I come up with a solution, I'm not sure if it's correct. Textbooks only teach what is possible, not what is impossible. So I'm forced to make up questions on the fly. What I'm doing is not working here.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the desired language is *finite*, so you can just go

$\qquad\displaystyle S \to 1 \mid 011$.

If you had recursion, say

$\qquad\displaystyle S \to ASB \mid 1$

as starting rule, you can *not* force "matching" $A$ and $B$ to behave in sync.
There are more powerful types of grammars that can do that, but that's beyond
the power of context-free.

Comment: You're right. The number of strings in the language are infinite. Another mistake of having to alter the question. If I give any more detail, I feel like the answer will just be thrown at me. The problem is, while they both need to be $\epsilon$ at the same time, they must also be different at the same time. To be more specific, if $(A = B) \neq \epsilon$,  $A = (B)^R$. The first part of my question was plan A of my solution, and the part you deleted was plan B. Again, not to sound ungrateful, I'm literally here for yes/no answers. If too much detail, I won't be answering for myself.